# issue rqt with ros2 qos custom proflie

Tags: mavros, ros-foxy, qos

when topic is subscribed in ros2 rqt it shows unknown when topic has default qos profile it works but when qos profile is changed it shows unknown again is there any way to set custom qos profile in rqt just like rviz